# jQuery- Stop execution of ajax request after X seconds

Tags: jquery

When a list item is clicked, an AJAX request is made. However, in the event that the AJAX takes too long or just hangs, I want to stop the function if not complete after 5 seconds, and give the list element it's original class, essentially canceling the request and allowing the user to click the list item again to retry.

```
$('li.alt_li').click(function() {
     $(this).addClass('altclicked').find(".fa").toggleClass('fa-question fa-spinner fa-spin');
    var theid = $(this).attr('id');
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
  $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: theURL,
        success: function (data) {
          // do some stuff
        }
});
```

How do I do this?

Comment: var xhr = $.ajax({ ... }); xhr.abort(); ? oh and wrap it in setTimeout of cuz

Comment: even if you abort the ajax request... the server side process will continue..

Comment: If you read the documentation, you'll find that `$.ajax` has a `timeout` setting.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, I know it has a timeout setting, but I need to actually do some stuff (change some classes in the list element) if it does, and that's the part I dont know how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

```
  $(document).ready(function()
   {
     var start_time = new Date().getTime();

     jQuery.get('url', 
     function(data, status, xhr) {
        var request_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;

         if(request_time ==5000)
          {
            //your code goes here
          }

    }
);

});
```

Comment: If I don't echo anything back from the GET url, it's not processed as a timeout, if I do an `alert(response)` I just get it like nothing was returned, but that it was still a success. The problem I'm having is that the page may take quite a while to process and return data back to the .js file, and that's what I want to timeout, not if it successfully SENT the request, but that it successfully RECEIVED a valid response.

Comment: I edited my answer. Now check whether you want something similar to that or not.